# Regex replace last "K" after number

Tags: regex

**Assumption:** 50k == 50000, i.e "k" can be replaced with "000"

How can I write a regex to replace any "k" that is preceded by a number with "000". Such that I can get

`70k => 70000
70kg => 70kg
k => k
70k only => 70000 only`

i.e replace if only, it's preceded by number, and either a space (\s) or endline ($) character follows the "k"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please post the regex you've already tried.

Comment: Please verify my code after the changes to make sure that it is meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The regex you need to search for is `(\d+)[kK]\b` (one or more digits, followed by a `k` or `K`, followed by a word boundary) and replace with `\1000` ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/12)). In PHP

```
$strings = array('70k','70kg','k','70K only');
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/(\d+)[Kk]\b/', '${1}000', $str);
    echo "$str\n";
}
```

Output:

```
70000
70kg
k
70000 only
```

In JS

```js
let str = ['70k','70kg','k','70k only'];
console.log(str.map(s => s.replace(/(\d+)k\b/, '$1000')));
```

If you don't want to match `'K'` as 000, just change `[kK]` to `k` i.e. `(\d+)k\b`. You may also want to include `\b` at the beginning of the regex (i.e. `\b(\d+)[kK]\b`) to prevent matching strings such as `a40k`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do:

```
var patt =  new RegExp(/(\d+)[k](\s|\n|$)/g);
var str="10k only";
if(patt.test(str)) 
{str =str.replace("k","000");
console.log(str);} else {console.log("err");}
```

Answer (score -2):

user_input= "70k  70kg k "
   import re
   comp=re.compile('(\dK$|\dk$)')

' '.join([val.replace("k",'000').replace("K",'000') if bool(comp.search(val))
   else val for val in user_input.split(" ") ])

Comment: Please verify my code after the changes to make sure that it is meeting the requirements.